# Bluetooth headset works well after reconnection

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 22.04

I use Ubuntu 22.04, and my sound configuration is set as **A2DP sink** in the settings. I don't know why the first time I connect my headset(One more E1001BT), it sounds weirdly with high bass. I don't remember to have such issue on Ubuntu 20.04 or mint. It works normal **after disconnection and connection once again**. I'm curios to know what makes this problem. I use Lenovo ThinkPad E14. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the info you have given here no one could even guess.

Comment: Would u please tell me about the details that may help?